# Is inheriting from a template argument bad practice?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

So in a recent C++ project I'm starting to find that a quick way to decouple a lot of code is to write template classes which inherit from the template argument. Here's a general example:

```
class BaseBehavior
{
    // this class has a well defined and extensive interface, however I'll show this function as an example
    virtual const std::string name() const {return "base1";};
};

class DerivedBehavior: public BaseBehavior
{
     // may add functions to the interface or override any virtual in BaseBehavior
     virtual const std::string name() const {return "base2";};
};
```

Those are two different behaviors which are then inheritable by at least two other classes

```
template<class T>
class ImplementBehavior1: public T
{
    // an important feature is that this inherits the interface of T as well
    virtual const std::string greet() const {return "hello"+name();};
};

template<class T>
class ImplementBehavior2: public ImplementBehavior1<T>
{
     // now this can has T's interface as well as ImplementedBehavior's
     virtual const std::string greet() const {return "good evening"+name();};
};
```

I used this technique (in a more useful case) in my code where essentially I almost wanted a table of behaviors. Here we can have 4 different classes with 4 different behaviors. I first noticed that this strategy could have the same benefit without templates, using polymorphic components, however my code didn't require that the implementations be dynamic at runtime, and this also decoupled a lot of code since I was able to inherit the interface without having to worry about writing a stub interface. Further it lets a lot of things happen at compile time which I'd imagine make it more efficient at runtime.
I've never seen this style SUGGESTED and it certainly looks obscure, however I've found it was the best way for my case, and I could see myself applying it to a lot of situations. I'm wondering if there are any inherent flaws with this structure which I'm missing now?

Comment: TL;DR; Why not switching the views, and have `T` actually derive from `Implementation<T>`? That would make a lot of things easier, and controllable. For more information see here: [**The curiously recurring template pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: Ooh so there is something on this, that's helpful. This is a very general case of it, the advantage of structuring it this way is a lot more prevalent. I was just trying to simplify the pattern I used.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called mixin-based programming and is, for example, used to construct layered memory managers. [In this paper](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~yannis/practical-fmtd.pdf) you can read more about it.

Comment: Shouldn't your functions be const rather than the return type?

Comment: Are you referring to a const-qualifier? It's not really relevant here but sure I should probably add it.

Comment: This looks like a textbook case of static polymorphism as opposed to runtime polymorphism.

Comment: Yes that is becoming very apparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're asking about

> *"Is inheriting a template argument bad practice?"*

I'd say it (as so often) totally depends on your actual use case. There might be valid uses, but more often these will apply:

- The template class should be a wrapper for `T`, then in most cases a `T member;`<sup>1</sup> variable will be the most appropriate choice.
- The template class should provide some mixed in behavior<sup>2</sup>, then the classical [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), where `T` inherits a mixed in implementation will be the better choice.
- There are rare cases<sup>3</sup> for the situation mentioned in the 1st point, where it could save efforts, when simply derive `T` with a wrapper class, though this might introduce further problems (e.g. clashing inheritance structures).

(1)

```
template<typename T>  
class Wrapper {
public:
    void foo() { member.foo(); }
protected:
    T member;
};
```

(2)

```
template<class Derived>
class MixIn {
public:
    void foo() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->doFoo(); }
protected:
    MixIn() {}
    void doFoo() {
        // Provide a default implementation
    }
};

class Impl : public MixIn<Impl> {
    friend class MixIn<Impl>;

    // Optionally provide a deviate implementation
    // void doFoo() {
    //     // Optionally include the default behavior
    //     MixIn<Impl>::doFoo()
    // }    
};
```

(3)

```
template<class Base>
class Adapter : public Base {
public:
    Adapter() : Base() {}
    Adapter(const Adapter& rhs) : Base(rhs) {}
    Adapter& operator=(const Adapter& rhs) {
        Base::operator=(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    // Totally depends on what needs to be adapted
};
```

**Don't worry:**
Plain inheritance is almost always the wrong choice. That topic doesn't correlate with templates and meta-programming in particular or primarily.

Comment: That's what I feared, I'm confident that my implementation uses it appropriately. My main worry was that it could have been enormously slow

Comment: @bathtub _'My main worry was that it could have been enormously slow'_ I don't actually understand your _main worries_. Templates design goes to compile time resolution of stuff and is unlikely to affect runtime performance. If you were referring about compile time considerations, such simple structure will be fairly neglectable, concerning overall compilation time impacts.

Comment: Well I'm saying that slowness would be an aspect of a programming pattern that would make it a terrible option when it seems like a good option. It could have been something like "in the long run the code will become incredibly coupled and difficult to maintain."

Comment: @bathtub _'That's what I feared'_ [**Don't fear the reaper!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IM0im3V8HlU) ;-D ...

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on the real usage of your concept if it's the best way or not, but using template classes to do generic tasks at compiletime is a pretty common way.

Atm I'm using a library at work for processing medical images wich is completely template based and work quite fine, so don't mind your concept and go ahead!

Cheers Usche

PS.: here is the template based lib: http://www.itk.org/ITK/help/documentation.html

Comment: Nice thoughts, but lacking a bit of enough abstractions may be (medical image processing sample, seems over specialized for me).